# Extract Image from webRTC Stream

Tags: java, image, stream, webrtc, jpeg

I am trying to extract a single image from a webRtc stream.

The stream looks something like this:

```
--boundary
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: 27778

ˇÿˇ‡JFIF``ˇ€C     

 $.' ",#(7),01444'9=82<.342ˇ€C          

2!!22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222ˇ¿¿"ˇƒ    
ˇƒµ}!1AQa"q2Åë°#B±¡R—$3brÇ 
%&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyzÉÑÖÜáàâäíìîïñóòôö¢£§•¶ß®©™≤≥¥µ∂∑∏π∫¬√ƒ≈∆«»… “”‘’÷◊ÿŸ⁄·‚„‰ÂÊÁËÈÍÒÚÛÙıˆ˜¯˘˙ˇƒ    
ˇƒµw!1AQaq"2ÅBë°±¡   #3Rbr—
$4·%Ò&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyzÇÉÑÖÜáàâäíìîïñóòôö¢£§•¶ß®©™≤≥¥µ∂∑∏π∫¬√ƒ≈∆«»… “”‘’÷◊ÿŸ⁄‚„‰ÂÊÁËÈÍÚÛÙıˆ˜¯˘˙ˇ⁄?ÏÅÊ¢∫∑[òYq¡©;ävh&Á*ckyöﬁ^£°ı®e6+°‘¨~’‰ëySX@óâÉIãr°ÃTÏ9ÌQ{“@3§ÌäR}hgﬁÄhˆ4º1◊Ë ÌHsN>‚ìÎ@
¸;Qä_zCEÜ!•<sÕ)§Áßj»müzq§ÌöÑÌG∏Õ«CE8≈%/“å~ﬁ*Tb≤z;béø˝j.4oƒ‚Kuonj§√dπ«
M”%»h…Í2>µbÂ7GûÎÕ£
àäõ™‘gΩDE7µ<èZaÎ@Õﬁ≥ÆÉZr˜¨˘Å‰“(∆∫V%ÿÎ÷∑nEb]é¥X§c7ﬁ4Äw©$1Õ4R4HUß‚ö)¬ë¢”OÛÌL$gÉHlfO\“Sç4”DâIKäNÙƒîQ@Ñ§ßRg“Å  E(§¢ÄÙQILAE/4îQö(¶“ä(§Fh¢Ä
(£öQÕXä(†a⁄ä(¶ £öZZWÑ†“—@òîw•¢ò®†RG•(§«<R˚P—ö-
wjm-;†ß©‚ô⁄ïh)ØLT¢°SœZî`“5Lï=Ía“°\T´“ë¢>¥ÒMUÊ§=h-˘”¿§=jUZ,;+≈4°Ó*–OÛäiOj`—P¶)•≠Zh˘¶È¶d‚U€€4èZï◊÷£Ëx¶e±,}zUòâœj®á•YFµQHºáåTô9ÎPÆ0jxˆÙÕIWgΩ7g|~µ6‰M!ïÄπ§& rF{ä≥hA®eπÙQ≈>ñn0=®2ìπ–⁄„Ê∂-œ•`⁄0∆?≠m[úÅäg<ç{sW„«QÕgA”èZ—á∂zUZ^îΩOÖÊû'•∞ä\RÖ¿ßÅ≈RÄh≈8{ı¶1i@…†SÖ[[Å*f≠gøjÊÌÆN?∆∑aïeå5#eêr1Î÷±µ[ˇPÉΩ~ıÆ
8‡åv¶#ë!dM„ØjÆ…Õjj6me?ù˝Àò’JEﬁ>È§+i†~ï#/4”Hv8Ôı§=3JsG4¿o“É”ä_≠'Õg•7Ω;˙SH9†`
g≈/JJqé8£ÎE è|sF)=({RR“q@4cÉ”äO©†hñ⁄C Gcö‹ 0:0Æt‰√úV›åÇ[lu+@ ƒlf_C≈1ÖXπM≤+áÉP∞œ~î@iµ!Á5"ì•RúVÉñ©Ã£m!£Âx5âvπœ—\' }}kÈsö
G;2·ÈÄv´W)ÜÕU«4çíΩi‘Çñ§¥!4ÃÛ¿ßöcS4”O^¥ÍC@Ñ§≈-ƒ7µ£ÈEä(=(ùË¢íÄ
(¢Ä
(§†A⁄ä(¶EP⁄ä(†ä(†ä3K@îQ@/Z;Q@   é)h¢Äíä(∞•¢é‘Ω©(•Õ∞bógö=ËÌKIE
ZNiA†B„4£˘Rbó∆/Jvi£•(§4<ïO#öÑS¡¢≈¶XVa[é*ö∑8©—çI¨YmNje‰Udsäô
©ì®„9©P
âzu©”ì÷Ç–9ÈN€ÌNU©6Á&Ç¨W)ûzTlß⁄Æœjç”ûù)¢(:f†e!π¸ÎBDÙÙ™ÆøJ§a8êû2jÃK»‚†ÔV°4»Zñ¿„•<g∑°N⁄r/<äEÿ6ÒÕ5Ä¶€I∞≥p3A2f|É-«55¥l\`UËt∆ñL≤ê+rœI
Ñsπ¢µúM«πm¿‚≠[i¿Ú÷¨6AG#ö£'"≠º'5£Gäñ8Ä©Ç„µ\E\S¿•úx≈(QåˆßÈ@ éiÿßcä\SõsNÅ“ùL>xÕ^≤ª1>›5GÁ9≈„ΩB*ÁRéA5 ?5bÈ˜ª#JÿV•ı4)<Lå2¨1\ÃˆÌe?î‡òõÓüÈ]@5Zˆ—/ (√û«––6r“¶”«‡jp´#µº√Á^á‘Uy©¡§"ÈIé=iXsı§‰Êò\O®û∆ó∂hˆ†üCäO¬ójN:‚åhÁ—‹–0<˚“î¥û‘}i>¥~Z@uQœjN)§wÎKE'nïoNõÀò+:¶iU∂:ü¬ò”7Æ≤˘U£5°˘–+˜Ôı™R.…HÏyÅê∞Ê°=˚‘ÌP∞≈3±™ 8<UÆ¸‘2é¶Ü4e\AèpΩknp+.·:“.';væıG≠vùx¨∂8©7[8ßqé)8Ù§P√L=Èƒ”M1\iÈI⁄ñõLB”OZ^Ùô†AIE†LL
)3GZçt4fÅázJ(†AIKILAEPﬁä(†ä(†è¬ä(¢ñíÄ
)i>¥¿)i(§—IK@-%¥¥îP˜£ÎIìK@ÌGJNî¥¿?3IK@E¥Z%-ñõN‚ÄüL˛4·H§HœÙ©w®GZx=ø≠)6XI*uz®µ*˝iX÷2/$ô´1∂k9ÙÕXç˘‡öF—ë©’a+:9@∆jÏRqA™d˚A∆N=i·ΩËbı±Y£‡Ûäß"Ìä—‡ö≠*Jh∆H°å61Va¿aL)œf›   aTdëh‘ëƒÔ¿´ñ∂à‰o$÷Ìùú p¥
S±çm¶I!~µm¢˙Æ?
Ÿ∑çE≠‘p0(±œ9≥&
$˜zw≠l{¬Æ
xÙÃ.1c
—R®†/4‡1H/µ<Ù™8ß{‚òÑ“”±öP¥õ{S±@ßw¶!Zv(º–`
ZFeUÀﬁ≤Æı1∏¨_â¶Â8«á≠;∑¯“Ü†`:
◊”ÔwéyÏkµ9´q∆;–3¨äp‰VmÖ‡ï1´@P3?U∞1˘±Ò2åµÑôNFx ◊[XzΩëâ˛ŸˇÆä==hå…è≠3´D,à$Sêy5\ézPMàÈ0s◊4ÍOÎHaÕ7ë≈8˚“bò ¡4v£ΩJNÙøJNî√©Õ
R8‚ö3H„ä:v¢ä!¢é¥îS÷ö√"ùI÷Ä4Ù…≤¶3‹d}jk§˘wc•e[Jaò0ıÕm»¢D»Ë¬Åô‰dTL9©FyS‘Tn3@t®‹db•#ΩFz}hü:gµe‹'+jeœjŒ∏Jí‚s◊I¡¨yk°∫è9¨Kï√Hﬁ%ozqGzkPP“}©ßëJi¥…ì•4îJN‘„M†µ&9•ÎHhîQä;P &äJ(¢ÉILB“QK@¬ä)(£ä)ifíä1LAEP“QEpÌGz(†¢íäZ))yÈ@E6óä)h¢Ä
;—E1ûMîPQ÷ñíé1@ÕÇé˘†…ÔKM•†.:óΩ6îu†.8i¿ÛLÕ;µ$ú1QÉÕ8R*‰ÍEJ∏™Íje4aS+{T€äïqöF®ù^¨E.*†>’ ?ùâöI5<»+=‰sS∏u†´ì˘á=i¨˘ÎQ™ˆ©6èO∆ö!ªê≤Â∏ÕZ∑Së≈Äöπo#⁄®õ∂Hp+rŸy≤≠1≈l€v„Ù†¬fåW—j§"ØFJyíúSÇ˛fÄµ É!ßÅÉJ;S1Ké‘¥‡(†)q≈1)›®‚é(‚°û‚8s∞^ÛQKpUN_˘V)3ﬂMåìü»U$&…ÆÔ‰∏ìbgnxQR⁄È˚éÈy>ïj”OH@$noSZ)≈©¿úı£ä
'·≈dX`SO^îΩ˝®„Ëfh»eÍ+°¥∫∆~ıÕg=µ√B·≥ﬂΩ=∆éúuÕ)ó°ÎP[‹,—ÓüJõ?ï!ú›Â°∞∏%y∑êˇﬂ&™ÀGN’’\@ó0¥nW6Ω¨Õm/#¯˜1YyÕ7TÚGÜ9‚¢#ﬁêÜ„Û§•§„Ω1à8§œ4‡OzC◊≠ ⁄ì4Ωy4úzP}('èaFO≠'µÁhÈG“ì±4}i Ω©(¸©)h8ËÜÁ"∂Ïe€mœ+¸´ÙÕZ”Ê1\z
E©◊lôı®òU€§‹áG"©g"Ä!"òz‘≠÷¢c@…–÷|Î÷ÆJ}*åœ¡©.&m“√ªèØ+n·ÎÓ@sH⁄&c`TmNsQûh)±§“w†“d‹J3E®);““P §¢ä%å—@%fÄ
(Õ¿(§¢Å-'J(Öfä(¢íÄ∏π¢íå–—IE1ä))h•=)(§µîfòE%ÄZ))iÄw•Õ%%;ΩîP+ãGQ@ä^îÇä‚““t•†äLä\–\ÛNœµ2å˙P+íÁäPx®Úi¿˛T π*û9≈JΩWœ‡‹—a©’≤*e'µSV©—≥ﬁïçc"“û>µ(ÈUïèjô[µI¨Y7ΩJå~ïöïsÿP]À+œˇ^§'ö∞ô>¥ˆ,kÔZ™f©∆=´F’~a≈hj€/≈k€YˆÀåqZ∂Î¿¿¶sL–ÄzUËî‚™¿1÷ØF8¶éY±¿SÒJ1NJƒ•≈Í`ú1@·Ù†. •¿£5≈‘vÈπ€û¿u5V+0E‹«V=Ó´…é"q”uT∫æöÈˆÆqûUõ=7nOaÿS∞Øÿ≠mg-Ào|™gøz€Ç›#P®∏•é!¿≠«&Å«‘º(¢I%‰‡VM÷†O=i‹gxì#–”è±§#5ëCr
˘•Ìéî3üJ1ÅJG9Õ'Ú§¡¨ÆÃ2ÄI«zË#îH°á9ÆS85OΩ16÷?)ÈLá?˝jß®Y≠‰z:Ú¨;∞Æ9ù¸Ë ê[tr.%CÇ*ª/8≠˝R«ÕhÑ~ıG#˚¬±N$O1H
›©>¶ûÀäg–P!1Hù)ÎGjNÙùz^˝©9†¢åw£Ò†≈®ÌI@îPP(¢ÄÖ;X(«≠43v<Îul‰é
ReŸ#.>îiíÚc'≠Mvò√˙pi™’^S¡´,~Z•3RUï˘™∏ÊßôÒöÕû^    §kUπêcäƒπìúU€©qúü÷≤dlöF©XçèΩ4“û¥√L@x§4R@òQ⁄íì8¶+ãMÕ!4n¢¬∏sE&i7Qas!‘ù)ª©3ö,.d;4fôìG4Ï.a˘§Õ3ö9≈qŸ£u7ö0iÿ\√≥Fi∏4ò¢¬Á∫ç‘õh≈f.Í7Rm£X9òn£u}h∞πòn£q•€I¥–Ã7Q∫ç¥m¢¡Ã√u®≈¢¬ÊbÓ£u&⁄1Ì@˘òªΩ®‹i1KåPÃ\—öJ\Q`ÊbÓ£4õiq@]ÜÍ7RÕ.⁄Ã√w•(jLR‚ùÉôÜÍ\“K∂ïÉôÜÍ]‘<”∂S±†ÛKûi¡)|∫Ïn}iG^îˇ.óg0⁄\“Ï4l4X\¿)¿˚“i0iÿÆbPjEcöØÕ85+ó£|Ù5:∑ΩPI1Vë∏©hﬁπm}95aœ5Q’òœ|“±∫eÖ˙UÑ‚´†œnjtZ
Qn3Î≈i⁄ÛÉYpút≠{5ÈÕë±jº
Ÿ∑+.’GØnÍFF„⁄Éñl–ÑzsWTp8™‚≠(8™G,É⁄ùH;»SÄ§ﬁù@E5›cRÃ@Q‘ö√ø’K˛ÓBˇ{π¶ÑÀ◊öîp©Ü–V0ÛÔ¶8…'©=>“¡ÓàíBDgëÍkrtâ"Ä1Ì,R›zn~ÏkF8≤zTëA”ä∑ÑÇ=ŒqävâQìUÆØ£Äc9>’N˚V‡¨g÷∞noyÎüZª.µsÛ¬≤•∫vl&I¶Öísìê¶¨G
†¬ähñfë◊ännï!“9ÈYåÌúfêıÕ?4”◊• ∞“8§ßs“ìê>¥¿g_j:wÈÈN#<~¥Ãq@\÷”Ø∞|∑<t÷¿ åä‰îï9ÁÎ[6õ‘FÁûŸ§3WÉXZùô∂î‹ƒîﬂ}@ÈÔ[bïêHÖ§`Ò@ŒFE8FT˜®XsÙ≠´cc9ãü%éQ±”⁄© õOZ    ±ı≈!#ûVöq@∆‚è÷óòÈÉ@Ñ"êÅ⁄óö?:'lR
^¶èz!#4îΩÈ3@√Ω%-%u£µËú«(`pGJ⁄ìCª≥
¬=+R∆`–œNEeW8»¨˚Ü‚Æ›¸≤ìÿ÷M√“)ßì÷≤Æf#5nÈ˙÷%‹›jMQZÊ]«™l‘ÆƒµDA≈R@‰ÊöM9•Ÿöv3sª4gäxJ]îôêÛF
O≥⁄çî≈vA¥˙Q¥öüo4c‘Ée]Mä1@l§ÿ*j1@Ìmˆ©qEC∂çµ.;—@m£mI¯u£‘Çƒ[h€RbÇ)ÖÜbåS®≈3büä1@
€Õ&*LQä√6“b§≈†ÒF*LRbÅ≈ß„ö\Pä1O≠†ÒKä~(€@‚ómI∑äM¥\,3büÅF;PqF⁄v.=(Õ¥Ìº—ÉN«µ0ézSÄ¢îRsN≈%-(ÈKöo·Fx†èzp®ª‘£$u¶!ÿœÌ£©£(›É¶#ä∞ßmßqX©≥⁄êÈWDbû!“ãÖä@ÎS«∏u´€ˇ◊R-±‚Ç‚Ï6:∂áäç!¡‰qS¨~µ6:£4Láä∞≠€5UR•ÕMç‘Àë‚µl…X±∑oz“≥sø≠7tuáß5•@‹C 8€ú˚÷=õä€É†>ÙŒY#b’qGJ“ØßJg4ê†sN¸)ES 9®.n‚∂M“7=óπ™∑⁄¨v‡§d3˙ˆäãq®LO'ûXÙ“«›_M{(EìÖU´ñZV“$ü˝Bˆr“¬;u˘F[ª…≠·œjb#é#ÈW!∑ß¨jãπàw¨ÎÌeb #è‚°
óÓ/!≥Lz
ÁouGôéÊ¿ÙÕg‹ﬂdñ,rZ™ÊlæB˚S$t≥ºçÑ‰ˇ*X≠˛mŒrjx‚U
î/Jb _N¥°
JR]≈´Gñ^V™≠‹«Z°shW,ÉèJãô¸˙”Nsˇ÷©Oµ4Ä4ÄäöjR=)ÑSLC>ÜêÚi¯¿&õè ê∆„úSëŸ0ÎIÔÕ4Û@ŒÇ ÏM~`*ÚüjÂ†ï°pÀ¯◊Akr≥F¸h[õhÓÌ⁄7œOc\„ƒ—H÷Û¨Ná‘z◊P
S‘lE‘[ì2˝”˝(ö`GZåé}™—Åª]xe>µP",q≈‚9§?Jn))ÿ§†Õ'oJ\{–~¥m&)‘ÜÄE)£•6äZ()`ò≈09„Ω&*  EEª„ï$uÍ+‚Cä÷Û|ÿzé
b›|¨√Ú§Qìu'kÂ∑◊ªœ5é√-Î@€+ÌÕ?Zú'µx¶A⁄M†Tÿ¶Ù†Ò«Sç%%%/4îá⁄ìΩ:ì≠7ö)¬íÄíüHGµ6íùI@    IN4î¬RRëﬁíÅ    E-!†9¢ñé¥¿)qEÄLbåsKER‡“Ì¢„F)˚h&Ä¥ˆ•ŸFÍLûô†^Êû<¨T4†PŸåv£ré’
.ﬁ∆Å‹=*6ıß`SZò
•§†P!p1ﬁåQﬁèj)h¢Ä
(¥RúRR– •≈ÔFx†€NPq“õör∑4¿}IÉ“¢‹E874…ó4˛’
ú”Û“Ä$RzêÑê`N≠ÔS£˙Ù™†‘™«9ÕããÜ©U0*™7f7Î≈
1‡`˙S’M9#0_jF—òƒBj›∫∂E5c“ÆBπaé)3¢3–ÿ≤œπo”¨{8∆πl∏§àõ5-˙z—é®[}—üJûk∏≠cÀûq¬é¶©≤-<âóvGsXw⁄π|«U{∑sUn.Ó5  ∂.HÏÉµ_≤“÷$êáìÙ»‘ßi¶=¡OïNÀ‹ˇÖn¡n®°QBÅ–
ñ8™‚De®p”Ê∏Ü’2Ìœ`:’+ÕY!R±[◊“πÀΩ@±%òñ'÷ö£´<Ÿ¬zXí‹<¨V>O≠0E%√|‰™˙w´ëB®0´ÅA€`áêÂ™‚¶• ”¶M∞≈Sﬂ"ßsO
*’Ωú∑
ê0£¯èJÆ®IsÙ≠4“Fd;G•]Ü⁄( 2ﬂﬁ4ÚM*«7KÅMßb§≤çÕßWA¯Uº÷˜µS∫µ‹w Ó(ñE4èZôÜ
0äC! w¶ëœ•J¿f)àœá≠H˝t“)aµY≥π0I◊éı_∑“ì¶ÄÍaïe@¿ı©x‚∞,.¸ó⁄«Â≠ƒp√ ÊÅô˙•ë?È0èùGŒ†}·XÆó°ÆµH"∞ı?≥JfA˚âÃ?∫}iä∆ASMM"`ˇZàèj@6ÉJF)1LÌHiqHE ı≈†É÷è≠Ä”“ê“ˇ:NîÉîÔ≠'Ω6´ *…˛UZQ≈!ê¡&«*z©«8≈HÁkg•%«Ôbœ®†g=u–÷iÊ¥Ó∫‹Vv>j`∆„⁄òjFˆ®Ë”L4Ê¶ú–!§ˇ˙È)M%ÎE.);–bñóP1†
1K¯Q@   IÙ•&öy†“3I@%õöbb˛îEáÈN∆i|≤iŒ¥T¢:p@(pSReTqM/@  ≤ùÖ£-ﬁõ∏˛6Â§.;TY4P1˚≥IäJ]‘¿.iB”wsK∫ÄÅE&h⁄Ä“R“~4RJZCLB~QK@R– ¢éÙPE—ä(•≈ƒ&)h≈/µ%î”±«J(•†
x†S≈ JëRÅà*A“Äüù8!¶!¡é)‡úÒH§sL´ı:ìPÖ#*Ç(∞£jπí}jÇUàŒ1ÎAW4£¡´∂‡nõ   5£lr¬¶∆–ôøgé+nﬂÓÉXñéA<VÙ»h8ˆÔEÜ‰i∂¢"B±èõ$dÙ®a∑û˙MÓN¬ycﬁñŒ√y7>ã[–≈ÄPe6Ekfê T_©Ój¸QtQw≈Eu©≈l•#√?Ë("≈ßíT›!«µaﬂÍÌ.UN‘Ùı¨€›A‰r]…5L$ó.H_NÙÌa6,ó3mè$˙ˆßCj∑π‹ﬁ¶ßäU⁄L®G4ÓM∆Ñ©Ùß™g≠J´œêÜ™zÛSG»€I&¨¡dœÜsµSZ1™D∏E4ÇﬂOH“¸«˚£•]»vöZöM8û‘‹”K~¬iÇ0∫tß
m8}*Ω'SGÁ@˜¶kõa&YGÕ¸Î1–ÇCb∑:’yÌÑÉ ﬁæ¥ÜcëÈ≈4Ø÷ßë
úÉQ;R"9˙”qœ.)§Pg4áß‚öG·@
ÈZVª«?)8¨“;–¶4uJ})\,ë≤8»#≤ÙÎ¿√ s»‡{÷ê<‰P?wjmeÚõ˝[sJ§Wk™πÅ.†h‹uË}≠síƒÒ»—H?xΩˇº=i!2∑÷êä~)§s“ò
«‹SÒ‹RP~¥“3O§"êÔGµ;¥û‘ﬁ¥Rë≈ï^P*÷>ïØ)
≥/ÀP) 5vdˆ™,6æEFMÚƒ÷I\µ–ﬁƒJ‰VãÜ9Ä‘mR5Fií0Ù§4ÍJoJ6˝)~ÇêıÎ@ƒ"ìå”≥M'†õöR}ÈπÔ@öm©
§Õ&i(§”sKÇiBS¥m&•  ≈;Jp@)≈ÄÈM/È@¿nQQnÕ&iê…ÈL.i>¥PM3ûµ%4–!¥Q≈Á¥RP(h§Õ†•Õ3'=(¡4Ï–Sv”∞£≠.Í3Õ®›@\\üJ9§…Õ/Z)i1J)ÄQﬂä=©E'z1KF;– ˙QKG4QåR–x†Êó¥{–&4æ‘
QL
z”3Õ<r(*ÉR™ûµı©óÆ("•J±”8©ó9ß`D=*A)¬û§PD^’ éúßöx#◊Ú¶
¬*⁄¶Dˆ§sR)\¸¶Ä%å`÷ï©≥î’Îcí4.∆¥!Ê`•nÿ€*pıïeŒøiÄHÓÕKx±å’Ì—¬õú‡
Àk‰Ö{¨À≠AúíÕœ•%≥N˚V$èÂOÁX2\<ŒV>OØ•9'lø ß∑≠Zä £@≈Q,Ü+^C9À{’µJzØJëRêXj&jPòß¢`™§üj“ÉOúˇ¿A˛t≈(m§ò·G…ÈZ1[E?y˝Oj±Ä;⁄ò‘:—üSMÕ
„∑RIMÕqsHM!4‹”B1≈8Sxßï&Å∆(Ë:Rä?ZNÙsGz=©Çx£¶÷≤Êçë∞¬∂ø
éhVU¡Îÿ–&1M`1Veàƒÿ"°«Z@DE&Iéˇï2ÄE6§≈4éhål8>µ∑ev&]§¸¬±Œ)— b` NEw:@y"™ﬂŸò∑''*}}©÷◊+<`˜Ó*»<‚Ä9Ü]Ÿ;p¿·ÅÏj"£•mÍV]n¢?∆£¯áØ÷≤]˘óêyÕe|bì©Ù¶ï†C
!ßêiΩË⁄NzSÒI@«|QN£Ë1Ma≈?öFÈ@ r’ ΩÖhJ*åΩÈVB#ÌXwjq[ÿcÈY7Ωh9∫”
HiÜò«µ%8ı¶PM„≠”I†=ÈîföOÚ†.)ÈM&ì”Çfò
£©SÇÄiàGû¥Ò©24∏P¥w†Ìı9¶M<ø†¶&íñÅ    IN§≈&(ÌK≈zP11KäBh›≈-!£ö0Mp)πßÌ§ P!ô4∏4qFI†AÉN¿ön
4πåÒF(«ô4ùÈh¶äpRRå–Åäu ‡8†••£Q≈w†ﬁè÷ìö_∆Å-%;P®?JNîΩhÔF(ÔKLBÅJ);“é¥ÏS◊9®ÛN›È@i‡‘Ω*@MLß•M∏Uu5"Ú)Å2πäî?ΩWˆ‚§∞åSÉZÄ{öïsLG≠Lùπ®9ÎVQAÔ@…PdÉW≠˛≈Uç@´Qpséhz÷M£5Ìán¿¨XX‡f≠F•˙ÁÇç]ÛöF¬sÔV`Ägs|ÕQ@†W‚ÄULTÀiÍús“ßä'ë∞ãüÈHÇ‡„n7õ¸´Íjƒ6©À¸Õ˙Uú–√pF†zì‘‘ô®˜“®†CÀSM&‡}ÈiÖ¬íé˘4ú–!iπ§§Õ1i §&£-œZg“äN¸R‘öã¡§ÌäQÕ'JCPh¢Ä‘ùÈO÷ä@G$+2ê:Àöâ∞
◊ÈDë¨´µÜhÑG„M#ä∑qàÙ„±™Á≠"#≠7n{T∏§#4⁄nﬁ*\R4∞J–I∏~#÷∑ ôe@ z÷ï=≠À@˛´‹S–Ø#öƒ‘,≈¨Ö‘~·œ?Ïöÿâƒä
=—%âí@
ëÇ
 9FL*3WÓmö÷Srßò€‘z}j´/µ!«“*R)ò‚Ä#†ÉO¿Ù§≈3∏ÏsF)f)Ø“•≈1«¿ß-PòVÑ£≠Põ–R2‚≤ÓÿœÈZó≠d\ì@ mQü|TÜ¢cLBL&Çriî•4”∞:]úS<pJ~—ÎK¿¿¥∏≈Ö0∂M H“¬örh∆ÖœΩ%.(†CqIO≈% ä1KöLÊÄ
C÷ó≠ı†ciqK¿§ﬂé)Äbóäni:“€¿§‹h⁄iq@94∏ßbäf)qÌN§†§•‚äLbéhÔK@
≈ßc"ó@)psN
i¿P@4†bóñÅç•˙RE
:J(•ÌöJ1öb
ZP“ˇ*N‘ΩE©E •«Ωè¬äZ`-/“êußä9G*äàpEH¢ò…ñ§^µ‘Ä–†q÷üäb∑
x4p"
jë“û
0&^æïm9™*¸UÑõh¸uj1“®G8´Q‹éî‘Ñt≠¿¨ànì<÷úhq“Å∞j¸ Ù&≥Ì•ﬁx<zöŸ∂í4È…ı§®-3É'“Æ™™å(¿™È85aX@<R“RÊÄÎII⁄å”}(ÔM'öZÄ∏‚iªπÎLf®ÀåÊùâπ!jaí°yÇåì˘’wπb~QÅM"[,<°~Ò´µ√ª˘‘aYŒI4ò™∏ﬁ‘¥î
»‹P;ÊóÈH:QÏ)Z3û‘cöJ(ÌK˙–{Rù˙RÅH)¬ÅËÆ§êk2‚‘∆≈á+⁄µ1C¿ÉﬁÅò8§ bØ\Z;◊ï™ÖyÕb,Svˆ.)¶Å"ô∂•≈&0(b Ë¬·ÂÈ[ä¿ÄEs<˛5£awÉÂ9‡Ù4£unóP4l9ÍÏküö"Õ\08˙˚äÈ3‹T3∆$\Rlg2H¶qû©ÂL¥ëÜ˚≠Ç*ˆÕ
ÎHGª‘“lz ÁµÊìk¥ò~„Ù¢„ﬁö¸
>oJçÀw≠2ºµü?zπ)oJœôè9†EÉ÷±nOÃkVÂÎw,ÿ¶
Qöy˙“h<Q∂ùMÌ@Hx£wTgÎ@«3
fÏäOz(Üì¶íÄ
1E!†Õ∏§•∆(ô4`‚ó Rˆ†Aä8“M&
u7öv1KåSò•≈>éÙÆ1≈-.(†aﬁíñíÄäZ;PQKE&)8•§†≈QìHC∆)xM4&Ói{”)iÄπÕ(ÈM“Ûöê)ƒqM†£•¢òw•≈E∏ˆ†4¥ù©p(q@£∑P!i{ı§†S‡äPqÔMöp‚Ä3ÈOS€Ω0S˚”E©A®á^*UŒ{—`ºv5*Ù®◊u<ÜòáÉÕ?&£∆*AÈBEı˝)™3⁄¶TÊòòÙïX@@˛Uåu5*ÒﬁÅì©¡´0 √™`‘™¯†FÌ•€`
€∂πœz‰°îÁä◊≥∏<sCC:Ày≥Z…¿Êπ˚iè©ù9©∞™„¸Ò÷©nr∏F˙∞ÕX
≈!8ÊöHı®ÃûıíùÑŸ+=F_äÇIÇñ≈U{≤ﬂp~4≈r„Ã|ƒ
™◊E∏A¯öÑ)cíI>ı"∆4hRﬂxìO   äxÖ8z˛îƒ&;RÅ»ø“î
.8›#≈!¬•€ez    @ÈıÆ•$IcVËAŒk¡≠oß∂ ©8Ó;Wq·}b‚[®£ÖàW`Æå2>µôΩªà=Ë¥üZ=È¥wÈIK@   ⁄ä(†pz”á≠4tß‡R¢É÷ìöZ@&29ÈT.≠1Û∆8Ó+Cµ!È“òL1≈4÷Ö’ØYÍEg˚Pi)sI÷Äı§‰s”‚)9†
K≥"˘n~eZºFz◊8¨»·Å‰V›µ»û0sÛ¢Åôzù±∑ú‹ß»@ìè≠gyí,ÖI˙WU"¨ëï`
û=Îúº≥ky|ïÎ{zP"Ìúfè1©1ë“íêÊÿQºÁ†¶‚ñùÄqojÇFÒ˙‘Ω™  {ÒJ√)Ã¬≥.`÷Ñ«ØjÃ∏8Õ2Óõ≠d?Z–ªcÕg6iåa¶såû‘Bÿ¶ìF=M0GZ3G·HÌEîîîÍn}®ÌIú
2M&)ÄgÛ£ö]¥∏ÔHÅöv⁄Z(òcﬁä9†ùii(w§•¢Äö){Rw§ ¢íóµ
9§ÕƒRRˆÊÄä)hîô•ÔF(3EQö.9ßåTy•êÕ‹ÛK∫òÖÁîg=)Z-è∆äb
Ë†„dQK@ÇéEËÕ/z:—K@Çñì#4¥¿Zv=i¢ùÔLC‘f•QQ©©Û@…c©◊Ê†CÉS>î'Ω;ë⁄£‹sO\‚Å«•\SGJrä§&…îäî6j%ZëE0&SRzbÉR=F)†ÛR)†(ß®ÔLDÒú÷ù∂r+:!œZ”∑^GzmZí@≠hO±Ì{w≠Hé)£úTægΩRÖj7∏v·F>¥ÑÀí\*éXUG∫f8AèsPf9bI˜50N=Èä√Bñ ±…>µ(AÈJ=Ü)ÿ†q–búÁ@ÎœJQ÷Å≈(ˆ§ÈJ}h·ÔG~)¥†ı°˘·Sø^kª-±˚\nG›«˘W˘ÄÔ^ù‡õmñÚ»G™èÊ•fo≤:·È≈/ÎI€ÅEãﬂ§¸ii:u4Q≈ é)E&1N~Z®†«4¥J
√#VuÕÆ¬YGÀﬁ¥}h‡úR©§€Z76ü∆ÉÍ*âR8¶x§€O∆!ÕG∂úé—Qàœ∏§ˆ†~“Ë∞Ú‰?CV.-“Íç∏Ó°ı¨åêkJŒÁÃç√ßΩ2dâ—⁄7ëz˚èZÑèo∆∑Ø≠~—t‚T˚ß◊⁄±NgpAÏiXD8†)ÿ˙P(§qU•<¥ƒTÊ"ò'<VUÀc8≠€Ø5èt„ûh*È≤jãUâ€-÷´˘–g'Ω4úSà4“0ú—ıßp;SN)ÄqÈIAı¶ÊÄ–IÏ(£Äi…4∏ßRS0(ÌKIèJ(§¸)i;QE(ÎFh†¢ÉÕ-%¥ÜÄÈIÕ8“cämÍJm-¥ÄJ)hÄäu%‚õäì¶‚ò§ßh€ÕJ¢ú#&ú#"Äú;n;—Å@1HE-!†ííäøç%¿vsIKE∏¥P)hM∏ı£NÙ¥æ‘SÔNRÅLBäëO5ÏÙ†   ¡„äîd‘HELå†d™=ÍUJbµLß∞¶    ÉRî*ìRÖ„¿NjdAúû)ù>æ’*äJ“§«=iàjU‚Ä∞¸ÈÍ9Õ.8ß/iäƒ±~µ©k€5ñúZ6Á†
à[Ä[V!x5B ’‰läCEàÜy'Û©¬ää.EX¿¥;
\R– öP2hÔF{P&áp(œjNΩi¡IÏh9Ì˘SïI˜ß"yÕYäë∞äIˆÄÅbÓ’:E¿¿≠XtuDﬁNê!‰r«Ë+f“’#Ï∂x˛Zœ¡?A◊˘P4õ>L∂O2·©≈zﬂÜ Èÿ˚ÏOÙ˛ïÂölaÔ#ßjˆ=:/'N∑åéDc?\sP∂6ëkΩ~ΩË 3«µ'z^Üä8‚íÉÔN†{R“≈(Ä(ÈGzZË¢íÄ
m)≈%V‚–≤®oø£ßµbï¡¶c“µn-ÉÇ»0{èZœe=∆)á¥‹TòÌA^iUä0 ‡ä\Rcä’µúM˚C≠S‘mH&‚ I«Œ£∏ı˙‘ÌÜSÇ+J9D…üÃSÄp√êzSqﬁØﬁ⁄˘dOıLr√˚ß◊ÈT ë⁄ÅfzÕûcä“ï}´>·x<P5‹“Ä}ÎÊWÓÎö€∏Aœçxº–êÃÊöfﬂ“§cŒ*2iä„Øjåıßìäa…†RS±F(∏4bùIﬁÄíîÊä@'4îÏ˙”M–“~4¥î¿(¢äC
NÙ¥S§•¢êƒÈ≈-PEá¥ù©h†«ÑR–iü•&)rh†Ù•ô¥¿>¥Rfå–—èzN‘fêÅE ji&ÄºÙ*#öJb%$ë@Œi´O≈†ä\RäèmßëœJZGÉö0qRbåSÄR”¬äv⁄åfó N)‚:ƒ;i·jMîÒ†D8•¶”ÑbòXØäpZ∞#óÀS\-.”åUêÇúGj≈`ı©îNµ ú‚§RΩ†V1ÌVUN8
úUà‹fÅí"±„<T´‡Êñ9åÒVH˝iäƒbzu©:TÈ,CΩOÁ≈€≠UX\TÀTﬂiàfû.°ÓsLdB~Çû!'úùo ©“Í‹û†õVÈåU€xõ)Îq ´PœlShP„êjÙ`‚¢ÜT8ÈW#d≈!éà‡Ù´9ÕBÖ=jpTÙ4Ä\¸¥‹úz”¬gÓÛOûÊê¥#Îﬁ§Tn¸T±BŒ€cRIÏ5§∫`Ü1-˝ƒv±r«ìÙ¬◊2÷<ï9ÜDPÃ§+t$u≠{hÃúizkMûó7cjp:ööÛCø6œssz&ëLjªQG|z‘¶∂0"æ¡‰+RÊ;‘ñ÷+V«+vU… ÁYÑmò}+≤∑åKek .ªO∂Fò`ãz]µüÃ°§îıñCπè„˛vêÄ}ij>NÌøü|´Çw2ØÊΩpzWú¯&€}ÙlW°-˘ÒØH)!Àp•£)(ÏÛIö=©»†•¿Œi1éîΩ>îÄwZ^˝
 ıÔKﬁÄGzJQÔ@!•§=h)8•˙RPéix†}ihï–  Gﬁ˛u=%&3!–´r)ÑU€µ»»ÎY§∑J@<ÅM«õõΩ=ËÌNäVâÚ)π>îüÖYY'á’H‰…û‹€KÂÛÂü∏OÚ©mÁ0æÑı©,  unU∫AÓ≠P‹©é’ü:u5±4L¨… ƒã¡«zÕùx"êå;ï∆EaﬁØäËÓÆb^F9¶uÕ4‘“&£≈BWö
äê”HÕ0#≈4”»ÊöGµ6êû)ÿ‚ì•7>¥á≠)§§÷özıßS`√ΩRg⁄Ä
(§†£4ôgö-ô£4Ü/Z)(†§˙RfèŒÄ4Rv£<PÊì•ÑÛ@~h…§Õ&h«ÉIIö(‘g⁄õFhƒ—⁄õE-Ph)@ˆß‡Q≈ ‚ùìI∏
Qaìö2iÖç&MÚ¬ìu2ì4¿ó}(oZã4g“Ä&äP˛ï„Kö∞$ß  *∂iwqEÄ¥%•Ûj∞cﬁå”hKKÊ’`ﬁî°˘†W,˘îÔ0ı5XNŒzP˚Õ.‚{‘9ßgµ'
ìN
¯‘û¥‡‘ƒZ«4‰µT5=[ö∫¨
ê5SGÁ≠Y
LDÍ∆§V ı®©ö`Jƒı†1≈"„“Ì†"∂{‘Í‹u®T (2±3VRVrj∫ÉR®ÊùÇÂËØ$˘™ÙZÉÇ¨ïqS'P#r;‹úg≠_ÜÁΩsÒ7Ω_Ç\w¢√Ωéäi1ä∂í[∆B±idˇûqåö ÖÂ~RJ®Ä=FFùtìj◊Ãùåz˜?•K–§Æ]∞∑‘Ø2ê*X«‹®'Á–VÂ∑áÏmœò Û\≥L€ﬂ>ŸÈZQ¢«TP†vä}gæÂ_∞ä6®\ìÅåû¶ÜP TÙ#ñä¢O?∫å«)VÍ≠É]Và‚]<∆‰œ?÷∞µÿºª˘ÄÓw«ö“ºπé‚.¿Üè˘
∑±=NÖ~Ì-5;ÁØSN®,˘Ô¡V€I1—¸Œ•v#ØJ√¥Vñ[}…ÈÈÅ[É•{ãö?≠oB@'µ;nÑ4QJi;PJ1öL~¥·öCä){–ER–!)
)§†“Ù§«4tÕ;R“
w·@ HzR“îÅÆ∫V~*˝ﬂJßRPÃÒ§∆
HE7ÃQN«•!Î@98Ω
É⁄±"\ÃÉ˝™ÿúÌ∑•4Öß⁄#ﬁòØ›>£“π©”#8#‘“∫[{çÀÂ±Á±¨˝N◊;¶çrﬂƒ=}ÈàÂÆ„ä«ªè Ê∫”ØCY7)¡†G/s◊Œj±Õj^ßZŒ4¿àéiÜû}i¶Ä#4”N<”M0Õ4öu!‚ÄﬁÙÓ‘îò§ßRbÄíùI@
£¥PRS®≈E)ÈF
%¥òhîsE%
(¢ê¬å“Q@Ñ¢åRbÅÜy¢åQäb
(§†RQEöp>¥⁄)~~¥“¬õÕ'„L-@9”@†CÛA4ÇÄ(z“p£⁄Z-%-£)h≈ òöu7Ï`P!s≈8n)h¿”Å4¡÷ú:”yßäéî(P}©Ÿ4‡h(«Zx5yßÇ:S(<‰TË‹UP‹SïŸÕ1’ªÙ©AÔT¸Œ=_ﬁòÀ»Aˇõr˙’zôNNh,´rjUnqÕUSR£cÒ°Ç.©«0léïQ$©ï≤(“ìÎRÉUA©U±ﬁÅcjª‡ıŒ+1¨∆˝®—Èó>\ÿ$mee?à5”Èóö7œÒ1ä‡·ì9ÆáO∫¿Ú9•$T^ß®Z $âp{Uä¡”n≤PcäﬁÌY¢§¨¬ä(¶IÃ¯é,]$Ä}‰˝G˘[√ròı!?ÎØ‚9˛ÜµºEkHﬂ∫∂?1ˇ÷ÆwMê√©¬√åH2}è˙’Ù%ù»˚ˇ•>ò~ˆiıû?§≈‰Èp'OêœüÎWzqMçv∆™;
~G„@\´!Õ–„ÓÆx´19xï±ÇGJ≠›s#N8mNO™∂Ñ‹]√—åÙÊ¢}·¯<»¶ÔÚÒ»ï-
2p8ÔJF$s≈IJ√ø•çˆ•†ä(ÌHbgäJZn2(3Õh†
xv£ö_c@   H‘øÖ#{“c3Óè?çU©ÓèÕPTå;RbñíÄ”÷üM?÷Ä%¥]◊(=ÎNÔàπ™õê}]Ω8çGΩP‹ézT¢1pﬂxŒ£®$ ∂E(j6˛Y.ÉÂ=@≠`›/ZÍùñd ÛÿäÁo†19Óüª˛Õﬁ/_Áä…qÕmﬁ'\÷4ãÇsL®ÿT¨*3LDg“özSˇZiÎ@4á„M†ö
/^E6ÄÙt§ÔE 
J))ÄQGz(¬ä3Ep¢äL–1i)3Fh≈Ñ—ö/jJ1H 
•ˆ†–bêäv(Ì@≈%?ò†ciih†BbåR‚ó‹RS±F(îòßê))ÄÃQŒiÙò9†BNé)h••⁄iq@
•Ì÷åbéù(QﬁóÉEΩ/zAÙ•Î@É£äZ(ÇóΩ©y¶bú:RSÖ1·J)ßP˜•))√Ù†ß
hÎÕ;Ò¶ÑÈŸÊíñòâˆÎS´Ue„©”≠0'Fı©‘‘å‘À…‚ö`L=jEa”œLSÖXF¸Í¬û*ödÚju8q[ﬁ§Sûj™CRÉä∂áú’àœ9ÕRå˚Uòœ#µ4°j‘≤ólÇ±¢?ï^Ö»#¥
;Å§‹ìgvvp>¯T˚WùhíÊ1Œpkª”$-”€•bÙfª¢ıQLíñ≠õ¶ …Q∏~L◊xóé2+–d£e∆r«≠pt¡ÕTIë›≈/ük™9t9ı09˙÷vâ.˝"ûP?Å„Ù≈héï,•±Â√“ê“îTw
∂>ÇÅêŸÚcÔjÊÎ◊•Clõa\zT‹ÉVâr£ñŒjÑ◊QD¡$b7tÕ^ê„üJ ºú˝©c0C—±“ÜR¬gÕå!,ç◊⁄¥á„Y¿ˇlY8ÿn;ÉZ†®ê‚(«ÁKEï!ÖºRRÜõŒ)«•0– •i;v•¸(ﬂJZJSı†¶9‡‘ïáÂ4ôHÃúÊNï˙S§ˇXiøùIA◊µ%/ZCÌö%6úy‹SÓúøºcÌSﬂûTS4≈·œ“•ªÑπ‹:Å“ò’Ç¶#ûî«)§|ôF»™◊
≥∆GØÈW'Z£!(säb9ÀËJ3)¸=Ît√]ÖÏBT'ÚÆZÒ0«"òÃ*9©ÿsQ0†Dt∆‚ûi§d`3ÈM'<S»≈&1@öJq¶–QA¢Äíî“PIö1E¥‹—@¿ö)3K@   ä(¢Åã⁄íóä(ú“‡P)p(üç¥îÑ˙—E?ozwzm
J^îPÕ/4ô£ö\Qä(Ì@)0)GZwf•ÿi€ÄÙ§2
bóòdÕ…†cç‘‹Êó<”á≠≠.3EåqKÅ“ó†sJ))h¥¥ûÙ¢Ä•åq@¶ €N≈Êùä`6ùﬂ•ÍN¶ùäN‘∏…‚Å¸È√ﬁêNÔöbSÄ˝i†å”¡‰S@.”SGå
Ñ6iË‘ƒZQR.qU’èJïO4az”«Ú®◊Ê•÷òRsS%Fº‘ã€äLßûï0&†≠KüC@2¬1∆3VPÛTìûsV£§4_äØBA¨ËèJ–Ñé(∏&ã.+æ—ﬂ?ïyæì&Ÿ¿Æ˜Hêí∏5î˜6é™«GE®¶@W¨D"æú¥OıÆ⁄π/57.ÉÎ≈4&_ƒª≠ßã∫∞oÃc˙V‹móe=F˘¸´ñÃ€o⁄2xx»«©‰◊G∏Gz£≥ÇøèQ¸⁄á∏&y«|U{√˚†£© Uè•U∏˘•âGÆMd €p1⁄ü∏“°‹»§„ùÿRÔÀ2û6ıÕ]âÏˇ®^7bPÇsÉÉRMúØÎäÑ".Uww u§u'¥äD∏öI√chØv™∂2˘ˆ‚R…´`qP˜)9ÎG¥îÜ‚ê”∫ˆ¶“Üö~î„LnÙvÊú:TA˝i$∏X∞>Û∑›A‘–"zZç%Ñb¢B2T‚§†‘3î‘«=*ºÁÂ§ Fkπ>Ùw˙”r3ö^*Fá≠/È(¶ëA†”@jÈ√˜˚’á˚‘À≈≤˚‘ç‘”únÀ(Ê©7‘njùÃ`Ç›
 3eù8Õi   *Ñ»Fh.c∑9ËkQè#pÆä·çxáiƒsl0j&ÈV•_òä¨‘¿à”*CÕ1®Œ¥”O¶`7ÎHi‘Ñq“Ä¯”iˇÖ6ÄÕ•§†§4¶ä7ΩÙºR–0≈•¢ÅàGz){Rcö¥bäR—H¢å—Õ∏Qä9•†–G•-!†ChÈKämh†P=ËÈFM∏†BsIöu7†öNi¯£e0#ßÖßÑ•U≈ -8(•S¿¶û¥˙i†Ô≈.M%/j_j)3≈P!Ÿ•ÎMÙπ†Rå”GZp˙”√≠(œZniA8†CÛÈKËi¢é‘¿uÆ{—”µ(†BÒJ):R–!hø≠'CÕ("®CÖ8uÔHæî·”9†d´”ÉS/^ıæµ84¿ùx"¶CÔU≈HáË¿Îœ"ëË:ÑÛèŒ§Fˆ˝)ã‘ùI»©ó$ı™»xÍzÙ©îÄNß"¨G√UUaÿ‘Ë‹“≈Ëèzø    ≠fF«?˝jΩ}y†f’ãÏïXz◊s•KÇ§•yÌª|À]¶ì&U®ô§›ƒKD§ıß‘Øæ˙Tı+`{Ö`¯ñ«√∂Tˇ1˝kz≥ı®ºÕ1œt!øßı™B9]&_#TÅ∫˛ÛoÁ«ıÆ≤˛C«&xV
è¸tˇËB∏êJMπIr+¥ø+=ÇJ9Vœ±~∏™ÍÆLUÙ<˛òaW‰GqN˜ÆKV◊nÌıwÜ∂¢ë¥u<ˇÖJ(Î6H£
¡«£qQ∑L:œS⁄πÎ_ëÅs>¨ü·[6˙›Ö»¿ò+œ«ˇZöìW‘ÖnUF2Z√$í1}ºÆF+L≈ò`'êVö 9∆ÌÀÓ(RBiè∂˘≠—»⁄XäüÖ})ÿ®(i†SΩÈ
 H~îΩi?ïx™◊≥˝öŸÂ∆vå‡U£öç‘2ÌaêhÃ€xÄ›Õ4kUçïU…Íqì˘U¯e9aeœﬂô∫¬ãçbìu˘z~Uü5≠’±˘‘≤g%á"ò\◊éEÚ€Àmë‰¸œÙ©„πÚ‘c˚®§Ók;ÔõsÆ‚ß‰ÓèzΩŸb ‡»>¸≠—G†◊)‡¯…Ry^‰·“´,Ä'ñ6ÔèûS˛Áäl”∂
∞˘ø∫9⁄=ÕK∆~îqH¨d)jF˜¢ä(π£Ωîcp¶Ä‹µ]∂…Ù†”„˘av b#j≠7›5e™¥¯∆)1¢ì≠Tô*˘™“-!òÛßZ«ªOΩ≈oŒµìtô⁄öÀ].÷&≥⁄∂o£ÎYi°ê0j3äîÉL"®DgÈMß˜4”@
4⁄wCI@
‚ê”à¶–h≈/ÈI@   E-îÜóPîbñäO¬äSIä(¢äC
)qF(¥S±G—K÷ä(Hi‘ÜÅ\i§¸)‘”@%(Õç'SGjJ-(¶ÊÅ@dRn¶“–∏“ÉœJ1J494º”∏ÖÖ1œz®¶ìFN(¸)9ı£&è•ñêR–˜£Ω Ëu/Zonî¥¿w4·L…ßîÓù©¿”;R˝)à^î¥ô„“ó&Äı•qMÊóúÒ@Ì@ÎI«•/·T+ùö`ß{P!Íﬁ∆ß
ı®«·R°»ÎN¡rpy©®Wﬁ§S⁄Å‹∞ß∂i√Ø“¢VßÉŒ:”$∞µ2úüZ™ØŒ*d$ü•;ÀJ{‘ËOlsUìäù8Ù•`πm•^â∏VzV£`8Õ Fú/Ç+±—$
‡ÙÆ'Î¢—ØÑNúd˜©ív4ã=KOp–‡≈\Æ{H‘hÀV˙:∫ÜSêk8æÖHuGqõo$}ŸH%-Q'ûL•dœ°Æ∂«7ûçà&—ˇ<!\ﬁ©ïw2cÓπ«”5ª·â∑YÕ<£Ó¸ˇÎß∞ñí8ó8_jÛKŸºÌJÍRx2}Ëó“àlÂêˇ
ìÕyúy)πà…9>Ùtzí{“á+åolsKı§;≤‹ù’°)ù>áäÿ∂Ò|—ú\Fí/™¸¶πô*çÃ¨Åà8§⁄û°g‚}6Áè;Àl„q˙Ù≠qu    P¬E¡Ës÷ºSO-3âé–ÿ¡Ô]µïƒé'èZL≥∏#˝÷Ëh™Zm≥Hä›Õ\⁄A‡˛tÇ¡÷õ¯R‰˜q@
Ì˝)¶üMÈ@ÜÌˆ•ÿj^3N≈f‹ÈPOÛÿ˛´≈cÕcuhAU2 9 È]I®gëaâùø:ìÿ}hó≤‘ù‘¥ø,õŸcê=3”•_‚X˜/À<Á‹’Ë¥ËÑ)Ê∆≠& sé¨y?©5ZhcÖÇ¢‡Ÿ4ôHåJu©MHƒÌHzußRS¥¯ó2(ı"öpjkE›rÉﬂ4 6˙'·Qï˛ÂBjÖqèUg´/UfÎIçw®‰-5ÜGJëô≥'Z π^¢∑&JÃ∏N¥ƒsWqgwÛ¨)ìkÍ.;ç`ﬁ«Çp*Ñe∂MFjf’¶"2?eHE0˝(√÷õRm–f)ßt§=hîò‚ùÉäJJ
-†¢ñé›((•«PqE8“c⁄ê ä)qF(R:Z((Êä
£4îP“QHh¶ëN¶ö7µ'zZJ
üZZ`†öL“fÄ)¿äèw4MHX
M¸‚£§Ô@»£5‚û9†Dôgµ7‡!àzÒE)£≠1 Õ.)(œ4u‹‰”®{ı‚ñö1N†•<uÕ7µ(<SÿœZwò3N¶”á4 wj/Säp¶iŸ†ÍO¬éµB1OúJB$Õ=N;TaÅˇP‹Êù¿∞πÔR)«zÅ¶{‘¿åbò”ﬁ§
PÜÎR!˜¶™ZôlÙ™¿ÛR«J∏¨}juo¬©+˜„2∑°†EÙnj¬>A™›Íq'l“IØC>5èò=z’∏ﬂ¶)Ác§Íå•UèN˘ÆÎI‘ÉaıØ$∂òÇ1∆
v˙5—!Mg$hüC–A„4Té^›IÎR»‚(ûFÖR«‘&9OFPr@˘î˘bù·iJﬁIgè?à?˝sRxòun√ù—÷nì(ÉRÖè1Ò˛µk]ì∂ß‚Y|≠a«ÃÚ=xÆFÆ£∆3oˇ-ëû√ˇ◊\∏»ˇÎ—–W‘^Oj2qü åÛ÷Å@»§Ó{÷m„e∆¥f'VM˜ÃqûÙ¨›=1C˚«8ÆøNOôkò∞èÊçN~U‘ŸáKñ,?*ìDwzWÓcG%W˘”Ô‘ˆÉe´û£f´üΩ@
cÖ'5Z≈ùÏay≥2$˚ÛNømñ
ﬂÀl}qREé%åtUR›∫“Sà§˙– ≈(
wN)Äﬁ¥÷@ÿ%A¡»ˆ©µ7°†do–÷Uœ2}+RSÄk&côMK:Rˆ†c4bê≈8«ﬁÉGz@'zπ`ππ\vÊ™{UÌ1s3ATÄ”~BjY:
à–"&™≥}˙¥’JRKöMç‚ÉEÜA2zVm¬q“µùx5B·>SLF—ı5ç{s]©¡ı¨´òè5dú¥ Uà®≠i^EÇN+9Ö "aÕ4äy¬)Ä¬)‚úz”{PO^i0)‘‹PH§=i¯¶öLQä^})
ä1KäCΩ‚é)h‹z“˜£ßZJ)9¢äcQ˘QöL“QGj(;QEË)3œ4ÍJ`6ê˚”øJµ IN#Û¶‚ò   A•†
mß‚íÄQÅKä1@
≈ÔO≈
h4¸qIê)wPÛE&·KûzP~¥îº‚ìΩgQGZ/Ú•»ÌI¯—≈/·K⁄íñÄS≥M£•0
:ôûiŸ†ÔÕ-7#•-1ÁΩˆ≈ı£4·÷îgµ ‰bîu∆x¶!~îî~·LBû¥º_•(=('˘ÕNû¯®UÄ@Ô@_ZêT@ˆÎNöwBqŒz”Év$èZrı˜¶"¬7>’:±ùUSŒs“•V°Åm\T™ıQ_ûSR´Êê#ìÒWbì=Î)XÁÆ*‘R˙ö@m[>XWm°ü›®ÆﬁBJÒ]ÓÑﬂ∫RLûÖƒÙ3>Gµ]eÖXdÇ*ûö¿€U⁄àÏ[‹∆‘†ÛtàXå¥X˙v?≠s‰õ5€›B h«9èØ_Á\L£å’¶g%sÃ|U(óXé>æ\y˙gˇ‘+ „◊ö≥´KÊÎWLGBsÏ*ØÛ˜¶ƒÄ±ZØ-À(‡u©X˜≈WAÊ]∆ò‡µZ≥e-#êaÉéOΩWüF∂`]öA¥pEhÅÉ¿®56Ÿ¶\êp|∂ò≈%ΩÖs'O∏&‚ØÕ"ÉÙÔ]û„t0H\˙◊7ß í®È„ÚÆ£NÕ,N(íIËRwGWi<Àjz¯<„4ﬂµÕŒHaÓ)‹m∆1≈Aª?ç@ÓKst&ç d¡íD^Ω≤3˙V†àò}J÷>∏,Á˙ë[ÇÇÄ—KÕ%söZ)iÄú“v•ÔE!ïÁ˚ßö»|Ôb=kV‰¸ßö ˛#ı©cB
wjLRÒ@'z^q“ìö'J”“«~ïõZ˙b‚>¶öƒΩ@®çK/ﬁ®èJDıI˘sı´≠ﬁ®ûX“cBRR—”öCj• jŸ®'-4#HŒ
f‹Gú÷‹â«Jœù85d›‰≥X≤°Rk®πãÔV‰$6hÃ∆MG–TÃ*"(3MÌRcúSH†C
&)ÿ≈4f
&)¯§Ô@
≈&)ƒbìîú“ö=y†¢Çh=zP1;—«zB}Ë&êäJBiøù0öJO≠–!h¢éîQG4w˜†äNsEòÊóèjCM∆)ÁÈM†bP1÷ä(~î{—E6äw§†“S©∏†≈9A4`”î.”NF
8†¶ëKAÈ@(§Êä1ı•§ßSùOz\QK@ÖÈKH>¥∏Ô@≈•ÎIä\v†Aﬁú1IäZ`-/ni(œ˘≈≈¸
:õﬁóåPÛÔJ:”1äpŒi°\x‚û  ≈F:RÓ‚òdÁ(Ë*êy5"úÛäL¶§ÈR/°4\w&åˆÇóö·÷§®∆;”◊•0%Sœ #ÛÔP®ı0”≠2Iö± ‘
9ÕNÉöE#J’π◊w·È¡ç@5Á–êÆÀ√ì.˜©í–®û©§ ^    ÌëZUâ°»¡Ó+r≥âopÆ˘6N‡`·ªWtFAµ¡›∆RgC’IïQ,Òóc%Ã“w99¸kgI¥µkI¶π¥ñ|∞DÚ¡»„'ß·XëÒ'π≠K=f{fÜ%èi$¸Àﬁ®ì*‡ßú˚™;Tı∂j+øQRG
    4˘”¥ïs#ú¸£0JÃ⁄ı™—ˇâqå‰yéâˇè≠ÎÍ+7[e+jÑıóp˜⁄    •ƒ—éó_fπyBÓ$‚ª*ÕØ-R‚Uïø0}ÎãHZ]ÿgöË¸?|˙d‡HOíﬂxiÀVTv7ÊöÊ—v¥n@„*8™–ÍœÇL`sÛúfÆ\ÎˆO¸.„”è®j1ﬁ(An´éçûqS`π—i3≠ﬁ´#ß)XŒ;í?¬∫÷πØE˛çq.:∏\üaˇ◊Æò})!¢ó•†R‚ì®†ìµ(§9¡ÊÄ)])¨¡ÎWÔ y™RPÏ˚R‚ìØñê   åuÔIJi(≠Ω<jß‘ö≈Ô[÷kãT˙Utìñ5Èäë˘o∆£j@@ÁÉTÒW$8ST¯§ ìΩ;ﬁé¥Ñ0‘2Ù59∆*   i†d.EPù:‚¥ÿqUe^µdw‰≈ªÉ"∫i£ÎY7Qg<bê§—î8≈Vn>µØySäÀa@»M&*B)ÑP)=È‘î‹R~„ÈöiÍ)ÄÜõåq¶Ûûh§˙QH~¥3M&ÉHH≈“göJ9Ì@Çä(†<““Q@Ó/4QﬁåP—⁄åsAqH}®ÈJH†¢å“fÄê““@ E)(Õ§≈.8†Bg4ùÈÿ£fÄÅN¿¶“}(&Wû`Ï*2i(.˛(…4¡“ú(ﬁ‘∏¶è∆îP!8•†ÉGC@≠E/q@∆);QLiiΩO4Í^‘£i≠.iÄ·“óîRÌK‘QE
QG~‘v‚òKﬁìu•ÔLC≥œzp¶éΩ)√<öaa¿‡„äëò9ÌKë¡≈Nò∆jP}™a⁄û
L2jAœ÷¢Rx«Jêz–¿Á ”î”÷û<~¥ïséºT´”öÅx©S–bòâ‘˜Ó*U$ı®óé5"éO•!ÿµz◊E°\ôFMsH≠iÈÚys.Ü4{âpß=k´ ﬁº˜D∫ !Õw∂Æ#µb¥fèbj„ı∏åzåºp«p¸k∞Ækƒë0πé\|¨∏‹˙Í–ô‡Ä!8„⁄Ç    n¥÷…ÕQù»‰8Ö\—”;c´`U   õÂ≠}5vY&xÕ•±u@≈bÎ-∫Ó‹Gc¯‡çméïvÀK”ÆZio£VrÅ4ÖxŒ{Q&ô»ÈÒ9µÛNu´x«Ø©\ÈÈ
XÿZ¬±[í™‰≥ìœ^ùOÈYKq!G°ÈK¡#4‹eiÀìÅ”öíéÛ¬ÒÏ—ë±˛±Ÿø\J€ÌT4hº≠&—?Èê'>ßüÎW˙qH¶%P(bé‘Ω©1@¬öˇvùMìÅ@óáéS*Õ·À~5X
õ;R‡bì'&ó4ÄCöBy†éy¢Ä˜´°ÄbˇtW>ú∏˜8Æëxå{
†+7ZcSÕ1∫PyæÈ™ù˘´3üì“´˝*X–îî¶íêx®$Í*sUﬂóö‹L"´H
Z™Ú
≤JRäŒ∏èÆ+RATÂœ]≈úÒXS≈µœ∫ªò¯5Ö}ZC2®»Ù3Ø5
å”M8äi‚òÜöC÷îû‘√@4“h'öaÍh'önhÕ!¶I÷î—H≈¥¥ò§ÌJ(†•≈-%-ä
%-P0"ì¥P!;ÛEs@7†ßRP1(∆('äL‰bÄä:“u£Î@u‚ñÅi¥Ïä(òÔF)‡QähßÖ≈≈?Øj@)G·Iœ“äåä
'z-z˛îP˝(Êéù®Õ04æ‘⁄wj:Sánî⁄PyÌ@©~î›ﬂ≠‚òÆ?=©G•3í})›∫R√øºbõ÷îS‹q≈;Å÷ö.F)àxπ"ößgﬁãé√«#µ.)ÅπÔN?âWü≠LâP£åÛS¨ô¶Ç?Nï \Tj˛Êûöy≈ìÕ.F(«Aﬁò;ä:Ù≈H¶èÁN\Êë$¿˙ù<v™ÎÄFXèµEò◊ {U»FÊ™∆Z∑ÅŒ)1ùNç©òX++“4mUKpk«‡ìhΩ+§“5#™1„∑5-ôÎÅÉÉëXﬁ#œŸ¢Ù‹i4ùDH™áëÎSk„~ô∏Ìpßı©L´j|„˙”HˆßÁ?•»Ù≠nb ≥∆H8Ù§KÀ∏! H0*—@µî∏8ÈËiùã∂zúûybï«j{õ◊û‚yàPÛÌ}ËfDû8ò©ÛÄ
 bÁúû˝i˚G8ÎÌQñfêEÃç–
Üsˆiﬁ?6F< ˝áµ;\JÂ“9ßFª‰P$‡T6ÓK†ïqF‚ΩqÎı≠{8≠§◊-„µi*êeP‡‰‰i"ñÁ†≈é%A—@Q¯Tò§„R1¥}E-¿J)‘òÊÄ¢óÓ‘’ÿÛ⁄êÃãúô*!OúÊR)©((ÔäA£B8§ßq⁄êÛ@∑]◊É›´¢<Fk…I∫å{Ê∑ü˝Y™±∆!ÈQ∑Z@S∏Ë*S‹}·P‚§°8ÔIäv9£‚ãn•1¢SÉRbé( c©¸Í)-¡O‡jÂ5óåS#*KqÍ:ß,ûOÁZÚ/Zß*Qp±ç4
s◊Û¨´ª`AÎ]´ÌY”¶A†F‚/-ÕUaÈ[w÷˘…±ùO ”¶5JÀäâ±LC4”ıß5FhsM?çÉ@Üˆ§•ÌKä`7Ω-ßHcqKå—EbñíÄäJ1EQEÎGj)(RN§«4ﬁ‘¥∏Êé(π£∂)h‰–;QJi1@É4ô•ÔöNÙ¿\–)3Õ¿§ö)π¢Ä≈:ò)‘£ß•;åS3ÉJÈ@8≈%zQ≈/ja‡”≥Hz”u¢ä=±@¥πù©q@ä;R{äZ.!G?˝z(≈/¿;fä.9"Äú
viºR˚Ù§1√Ω4î£ß#Ω2l(ßjOJQö¸)√4ò£ò!€©G±†cΩ.
a√!™Un’2:Êûô¶"¬ì”Ø„S)5÷ßQÔHdã»ßc◊§\u©3Ëz”‹uÊùöN£˘”Ä…ÁØjB$CœJ∞Ñ}j®ˆ©ë≥˘PRE‰=
∑Á¸k9ä∞í`rhR)1œSı´\m Ê±RLésV£ì“=C‘≤ìû‡W_Á-Œù,LO# üŒºrﬁ·◊Óí+J+…@˚«Û§“-NußènæıQß⁄3LäWñÂG8ˆ´%B=4”k1ú˝*‹Y«Z≥I∆j[åò≠'…Ãl∏§∏W∑P;}—[~‡P@#'úQqÿ ä⁄h ÛG»98‰ALÚÒ‘sÙ≠löBp
+é∆^’≥·ò˜ÎpìŒ¿Õ˙c˙äáÆ—˘T±LˆÚoàÏlu^(πIÄ1öZ·∆©y⁄·˙x’´=JÓIïLŒr@ÎKp±◊
\Tc%{“„ÈÿCÒIäo‚h¸h¯™Û˝”S†»$ö≠tp¥Ücø˙÷†}):π>Ù˙ëÜ=®«•(ÈäC@ÜÒHyÌJhÈLzjñ∫_`kj_πYZ@›;7µkM–SøjçÖMQ8†e˘o¬¢©¶í¢∆:Tn)iÿ§#ë@
§¡ß—äwò∏Õ.;Qä@E$y™r≈Z8ënÌLib¨˘·‚∑•á⁄®KÁäÊÓ≠Œ≈sóê|˙◊mqÁä¡‘-≤ƒs,*&’ôT£ï®
b 5ÕLÀL"Åw•«z\P1öL0i¿R‚ÄG•'nÙ¥6ä3IﬁÄﬁÉIÕZNih¸hQG„EQK@A≈'„N˙“P1;QäZJ%Q⁄Ä”ﬁúi3Ì@ÜöJRi3@ƒ¢åÛI@'z3A4ƒ.x•…¶fävhiùÈ√9§Ä“é¥Çó$Pæîi£èZ``RfñÅ¿≈§ó‹–0ÏSE:ÄRˆ•œjLgΩ8r(•È¯–rO4¥Q@∆h§•Ô@œ=(öLú—ú”Óh≠7=®Õ0%öp'÷°˘“É˙–ùNN1RØ>µX5Hßö∏≠ÉöùMSF‚ßFÊÅ´wˇJp59 <P-gèÎä3Ëi≠”ØJnr(&‡:öëdı8™¶úÄE‰óﬂÚ´(ÁÇz÷r?L’∏ÿÒú–ƒãÒ∞Ô˙U¥pqå÷zzÉ˘öπ    ÜŸ£ı˝*ÏLO¨¯[ß“ØDIn–‡dnxÈV4‡M∆}*ëÎ÷µ4¥·ò˙ÒT¬&¥cÎW~^?Z≠Z∂£äÅä)§ÛÌJ«
id“(n3GÁJ>¥wÈﬁêƒˆŒ))H£åRÕihÒ˘ó—å˜Õfq“∑º;nÒ¬ä§3ß«bóπ£ı™ N˘§ßv§†c◊Ñ™Wdm´˝≥ØN˝*X#/”áZAÔN≈!Ö'ÎN¶ÊÄ“õK◊•!¶3WG_ıå}ÖhÃ3¥U= b?ÌUÈ~˙S\éi¨*\sök)Œî~”1R…˜€ÎL≈ åQäv9£ïò4òßcö)X‚î
\QﬁùÇ‚c÷åSáR∞4aπ"´Mm¡‚ØÄ)CSœ‹AÄkÚ◊ Ò]u≈∏Ù¨{®@Œh8F»ÆH+≥öÌÔ`Véæ’ Í€≤ÉLFs(≈FE?>¥á˜†Dxò¡≈HGµ0é(1E”M)¶–Q¯“^(¥P9ÈK“ÅÖ&8•œZ;Pé(Õ&;“‚Ä1KÉG“ä@'µ&i›∫Sh(•˙Rw¶Ph4îoJL“QIÕ1!4})3@SGz;—@å—ÅG4¥Ä@)iÿ£Å@
∏§ó4¿_j‚öiq˘–w£øZ©3@÷åög4¥~I•œΩ3µ $›⁄ù∫¢öx4isÕ0}i{”ŸÊñô“é¸fÄûisLÔÕ&@Ô@â7bîè<äp8È@–ÏÒÌHHÔFxÎI‘”üJpÈ÷ô¯“ˆ«jx#5"öÉ>Ùı˙P"“0œ^j¬?÷≥¡©—ŒO|6G~(l≠SG®ÈS°˘hÿ~§‹bêÇi;ı†ˇúP+
#ûOJ3˙Rï…ˇ
CH  Ë8´Qì¿5Iz:û6¸©∞π£˙Wb#¨ÿ»»≈\Ñ·®∞∞ê1ZvÆùªà¨x=øïi€∂Ä<ˇØ9≠Ω9B¡ı5ÇN4ËıI‡;UÜ—Í)
t•Z}+çMz‡dd{T√_ªÍ
˝6“éµç7=∫◊)ˇ  ﬂ¢ü®©^π$)„“ê—“ÊÉ¯÷zµ√‡·@˙Rù^em•Tì“êÕ√Ì⁄ìÔYñ∑”œ"Æ’¡lg€/ÜîØ7Dz¸ü˝zb–Á{◊S·ƒ€éGV¿¶¬*?ÁÏˇﬂø˛ΩjYX5úPêsù∏¶ÉKE&i¢"z»‘ˇ≥©?6Ô™bO∏¶Ó#ìRãxÛ˜˙‘ÅtP?
5ÄYWƒ`÷¨üv±Ôè8©SsK@˙RÊÄ–JolR”I‚ê¿ìMÔÙ•'⁄õì@îò≥‘Ê≠≤Â≥PÈ£1˝*¡Ù™*7;
â˙C3ús¯”Ê•#&òigZCN#öiÎ@ÑÌG·KI˛M%ÊîQ@    úih¡Õ†bÅHHQìN«ƒ¯™ÍE’Ç,•BDø(>‰“m!•s´ñ]√b≥.cŒN+â7O˙¬c1=M.tW≥gCssX÷‡É≈Tuö•*s÷éqrX°uéBjæ{∑*Ê™8¡™π
X_ÂHxÌL
FÍbΩ741¶gû¥\“fì4îæ‘ºP)h£QﬁäZN‘w£éÙòß`w§ÔKﬁÅáj^‘Rûî”ÔMÔN¿§§RR”iÄfõöZC≈i
:ê˛⁄JZi=®ÔHsKÌIL©•‚äNzfÄ4göJL–+é›A>Ù‹Ù¿•§1CSÅ¶{SÈÖ≈Õ(4ÇóP!1ﬂú”È1ı†““—⁄Äñä=ç≠8SE8P1A•“SÄ„µ.isE”◊•œ·Jzˆ£ß≈`˝(„•‚óΩ––I˜£ÚE/C@E“«Ω/÷ãà7q«Zv}©ü“î8†.Iül”—˚öÑqN–SR⁄1ÕYLö†¨}jƒm«Zﬁ•Â9Zêr:T1∑åTÈÈJ„RÈ”Û©1I‘~4Xd]Jë„q÷ò@ÔJ8„\ãbaWbl0•fD√ÈW!êg P>¶¥/ìÈZ0∑OJ∆ÜO|Vå2}h
é!Úç@#/ œÎZM<
`áéÙÏORÎ-'&⁄WïYAÎäÜ5»º™Ò∏ı≈YÚõ8'<˜´)h|ΩÍßfxjróîùß*::‘…;dUë∞˜ß¨C§jÒ≈#B≤LYãD-Úı„öôTs”ÎR"~ÊyÍõr}Èuπ°†√Ê^Ÿ≈é≤+6„ü“ΩAW·[}⁄ÃDÄU∑LZÙ5ÌMóaÁÅE!#•J8uß
hıßåPÅA˙R“äNïãzOôèzÿòÒ“±.âÛy©cD]æ¥ú—ûsHH§O4∆4ÁÇ)ß•}È-I€ﬁÑ…uúöh÷Z é“5ÙQS”#˚£ÈRbô#H‚°óÓü•Nzu®&8CHeÎQûiÓy®ÿ“Üõﬁå”wP©)3HÚ†båRNÌ“Ä
_zm.hkŒ¸VKk◊6:èÓäÙ:‡<Yg(’⁄HÊ•ä∆—å{Ù©íæ≈¬V‹¿QÅ˜ÿü®ß¿à¸i≠‡y?3NÜ¬˛‚SnõèNMg»Õ=§F‰„èÁU‰˜ÕV˚\†Ûåè≠'õ#u«◊öj8â*è≠Tí<’ßFAÖB ∆≠&f⁄e\gz∑$f†d"¨ÃçÜiÜüœ4“(¥¥v†P–(•†QEsE.)c<—÷ú8•òƒ¢ùHi”ú”
<˛√@   öBhÕ4öb∏§˛4ﬁqö
&hœ)¶óÎMÕûÙî¥S;—äZ9†ì¥RΩ®«L
u%1X1G·EÜ†”pi¿bòáÁ4£`‚îP1r(ÊÅú—é(Éù&(•†Ú?1GjJQúP1öJ^x†  •¶géÙÒäpÈÕêSÜ)àLQ∑ú“–z“ﬁ˛‘ÏRJ(ùÛÕı•¸h=•0∞ÉﬁÅÈJz—@ÑÈIﬂÅJqH:P!FGjp¶ÁéÙ‡OC@/ìV5]*¬ìé)‹{#'<Ù´◊ä©˚µep}
@XQœ§sìMé¥·◊ìHwTc$”NŒ)‰»¶î¿rü^
Oû3Us¿≈HßûE
8ú˜´Ié3≈cFˇSWaóéΩË XÕ7 N+‹tÈ“ô"úUÿÃè160‡’≠GR1,vˆ˜QI∆§mˆ9'‹V[¬Â≤ßú˜5m-¡∫Æ~î1‹ÑOs!ƒËµa-ıF0∏ıÃ‘ˆ„ÏŒL_!#í*ﬂ€ß<âüÛ©–
Q«®A"…,xç'r“2yëæ’4Œ⁄0úÒUß∫ô‚*“ßØ=i˙tåˇæ¿`ÑëÙË(±W:ﬂ∆Zˆ‚S¸?Sˇ÷ÆÃfπ«˛Ö<ƒ¨ìêˇÎ◊P*Jb—IA¶‘”≈Fµ(†C©Ñ”˙
âè4ÜApÿSXS∂e<Ê∂.[k
FÃåi1ã∫ê∑lS7zSI˙P+è-≈0”K{”qEÜ<ûjKoöÊ!Í¿~µX∑øgOÊˆ.?ã4 G\ßëSë≈Tà¸¬¨<®£ØÂL@’Zrd”.o„â2Ã®=Õ`_ÎÒm+yzÙÜh;f£…Õ`m∑xœ˝ıM:—ˇûG˛˙¢¿oú˚“VˆÀu˚ÍèÌó«˙Ø¸zÄ7h¨Ìóˇû?¯ı'ˆƒüÛÀˇ†gAKû:Å¯◊?˝Ø'¸Úù!’•Ìè©†àcë˘“ÒÍ?:Á?µf˛‚˛¥ÉUü˚©˙–#§»˛¸ÎãÒn÷$\˝’Q˙f¥?µgÏ©˘¬ΩïÓ/‰ë¿‹q”ß
êˆ≈]”a∫`˛UK'<qW,3∂~ÏLCTâ8∂L∑÷§U©guHâÌHDa)≠Z–S⁄Äπú˝j¥ë+VD‚™»ùie<dÄä–ï=™õéh≈fåRÅÔ@√˙RÅÈJ=ªPc>‘}i¿RÅ@
«4‡)v”Ä§1∏ÔKä\PyÙ†“SÈM<PZò~¥ÛL4ƒ'˘ÊösJi¶Ä©9•Êõ@É<Qı¢ä%P)à(Ôä1J 
JZ9ÕbbíñóP!>¥Ωh∆iq€µ/PÎH~¥ù®˚∏‚åÛIÉG÷ò){Që“é‹“(¸(È“é˝)Öƒ„8≈!ÎÈG~i?)s≈'j1œµaE8o≠≠dÄ˜œûlTCÉNÅ‹êpi«ìQÉNœ=hy˙—J=3@†ˆı†Êú~¥ÑP&7úÊêRú“sú”j?ZOZJ®ÓH•õ¯“{–íÜı:I«z®≠=[ö—çÒﬁ¨∆«¨Ë»8ÈWc<wÊÜ4]èü•L¢†àÛ¸™“˛tÆ1ª{S
úëÔV@é)•:ö`ÆT+ˇ÷‚îúöô◊©Ãa±ä‘êc5f7„Ø÷™éN=jx¡Ë?Zbæ°ê1˘”$#ÆÔjÃüt{¿v„ﬁ®¥ØÉÛŒò»Àåz’ÑGu ©∆zÅ\Øö‰˝„«Ωv\ÌÑQ®c$˜&ÜÏπ]é÷√qı•‹3å‘~"êπ∂;B∞n^    ïâ>GŒ›}h5ÔdŸl˘‡‚µÙ®ºü
…)2»ëÆGLeèÙ™ë[≈uj´"7•u⁄Vçm%¥pªJ—©‹∑ß“„Vÿ‹ºB=˝‚Õ˙ˇı´o5Z⁄Ì‡H¢]®£TÊ†∞œîgöi†u†   î‘√•BΩ*Q“Äú
ÅçHƒ‚´π?•Tº|!˜¨˘'ö‘ø'i˙V.NjGb]‡änÍe7&Ä∞˝‹`SKqQízRs÷ÄøﬁÆÈ5ÍúÙ…˝+4ìZ:@ˇHc‹
h
´ª—gne€ªêŒ3XóÌÃπ
V5Ù^OÁVıø¯ÚQü„˛Üπ ñKáëã;31˛#…®ìN4√÷êÜ⁄åÙ„“ö‘ä∞d(‹:
n);”Ì‘Öª“JN¥Ä~„Kªﬁ£•4∆?uçDIRÁö~ÏûµúÌõá5xìT?Â´˝hB`j’ØÀmxƒ ÂU∞1V`ˇè[ØC~hõú÷Â/‘T —éÆ?:®"Fú
£ñÆ§Ÿ⁄Âà∂Ñs– ©å/6!¸j?O:õ◊Û≠h≠†)«◊?tVÒ†b†B…4_ﬂQ¯’Y$ãìºSuÜƒpÄ‡+âı†fåíFz0™ím=
VÁ≠<uá`#÷ú(4ΩËw••ÈNQ≈!°ùÈ¿S∞(¿†bRûî∏§Ù†aM=)ÿ¶v†CIÊê˝h&öyÕ0cZöM)ÎM=(¿”ON¥¶õ@ÇõJiò  KG“R•ÊéÙS
Ö¢óµêÏÁ•!ÊÉ÷ä>Çóﬁìî;—ö1J(ò&î(ÈJ{P“îJ4ßµ øJu≠;àŒ3G4„÷íÅXoµ%;©≈'µ&(•#ö)ÄùË:SáJLs@≠`ÈÈJ3ÔMÕ(˛T

û)≠7•:Ä∞p)€≥Qw• Ä…ø≠ ÈöwΩ1\OZCNÇh>îÉR<dQ”äìz˝iÑr(∏∂zP3N=)•;âj√◊Ò•iáÎN⁄ãÅf<µv"9«≠g'*‹,qBc5!8¡ÁØqW#8<VtÅüZæÑ‡sKq≤»È»≈!.)cÊ§aÅö°_å«ÈVvÇ*2¢Äzë)‰‘ G∑ÁQÌj@\t≈küˇŸ

--boundary
"next image"
```

What I tried so far is, removing --boundary, Content Type and Content Lenght and just saving it as an image. But that doesn't work. So now I don't exactly know how I should approach this problem. Any Help would be welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Your approach should work, as long as you remove any line up to and including the empty line before the image. The remaining 27778 (parsed from the `Content-Length` header) bytes must then be copied as-is to the new file. If it does not work, it's likely an encoding issue (you want the bytes as-is). The result file should start with `0xFFD8` (JPEG SOI marker) as the first two bytes, and be a valid JPEG file (assuming it was in the first place).

Comment: Are you working in binary mode?